# Animation not working after appending node group

Tags: animation, node-editor, append

I have a question concerning node groups and animation.

I have a project in two files, both containing node animations. But, how can I merge the two node configurations together?. Of course I can re-create the node circuit manually in blend2; So I did. But then I thought there had to be a better way to do this, and the words *Group* and *Append* came to mind.

The appending process worked; but to my surprise, when I connect the appended group to the node circuit of blend2, everything works except for the animation.

Is there any specific step or configuration required to append the actual animation together with the rest of the imported node configuration?

Even though my question is generic, the two blends are available (if required).

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Sept

Comment: Yes, please post the blends.

Comment: Also, are these material or composting nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The animation data is getting ported with the node group, just not applied. You can import a whole scene and it will work fine.

<sub>No solution has been found to re-link the animation data.</sub>

Comment: Yes, the two actions can be found in the Outliner>Datablocks>Actions section. They are just not linked to the right "user". Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Sangreelah It works if the whole scene is imported... if that is any use to you.

Comment: Yeah I have just tested it and it works. The only problem I see with the work around is that it involves importing a bunch of elements not-needed(like the cube and lights and so on); my project is nodes only, ignoring any render layer. I wonder if there is any way to link the imported action back to the right user.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do... Not easy though.

Comment: Sorry I missed your question above; they are  composite nodes but no render layer, only a image and texture input.

Comment: @Sangreelah Okay!

Comment: @Sangreelah if GiantCowFilms has solved your problem you can accept the answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers